# Make a search between 2 NSArrays

Tags: uitableview, nsarray, uisearchbar

How can I make a searchbar that search between 2 NSArrays... cause one is the cell text and the other is the cell detailedText...

For example I make a search of "87" and return 2 results:

1º result: CELL TEXT: 87 Restaurant CELL DETAILEDTEXT: 5425

2º result: CELL TEXT: John CELL DETAILEDTEXT: 8790

PS: sorry, my english sucks.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that just as you would in one Array.

Comment: Any suggestion as to how to do that in your post?